# Scrollable gallery in android, deallocate memory

Tags: java, android, bitmap

So, I currently have a recycler view with gridlayoutmanager which through a listener loads more bitmaps asynchronously. Problem is, when I scroll too far down, program crashes due to the fact that there's an ArrayList holding 1000+ bitmaps.

I tried to compress bitmaps with an inSampleSize of 8, and to load from the thumbnails, so my guess it that problem resides in the array holding so many bitmaps.

My question is, is there any way I can, say after 200 bitmaps start to delete them from the array without breaking the scroll system? After deleting them, how would I place the Cursor to start getting bitmaps again? I can add a function that after 200 bitmaps gets called, but I need some hints in order to implement it.

I guess this is a very code-independent question, but in case any code is needed you can have a look at [this repository](https://github.com/juanchi35/Megapho-advertisement).

Thanks.

Comment: The `RecyclerView` should handle this automatically. Just decode the bitmaps asynchronously inside `onBindViewHolder` and set them in the respective imageViews. The old bitmaps will be garbage collected.

Comment: I have not done any android coding as such, but *generally* you could extend `AbstractCollection` and do the "removing" or deleting of the entries how you want and when you want if that is an option...

Comment: @NabinBhandari Makes sense. But as the onBindViewHolder is inside my adapter, how would I call the scroll listener inside my adapter?